# socket linux c++ (poll, select, epoll)

Tags: c++, linux, c, qt, сокет

Мне нужно в неблокирующем режиме сокета бесконечно считывать данные со стороны клиента, но проблема заключается в том, что приложение является многопоточным. Как минимум, в другом потоке бесконечно на сервер посылается эхо-запрос и вызывается read для чтения данных. Проблему гонки данных можно решить мьютексом, не в этом суть.

Я хочу понять, что на сокет пришли данные, чтоб уже выстроить логику, читать ли эти данные в конкретно данном методе или нет и т.д...
Я правильно понимаю, что poll/select позволяют отследить, что на сокет именно пришли некие данные, или только то, что он может отправлять/принимать данные физически, так сказать?

Comment: Для чтения poll/select говорятт, что recv не будет блокирован, т.е. в буфере есть хотя бы один еще не прочитанный байт. epoll (в одном из режимов, насколько помню он называется edge) срабатывает при поступление новых данных из сети в буфер.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я специально перечитал это место про select в книжке Стивенса "UNIX. Разработка сетевых приложений"

По моему, - да, Вы правильно понимаете.

Как пишут в разделе "при каких условиях дескриптор становится готовым?", одно из условий - "число байтов данных в приёмном буфере сокета больше или равно значению минимального кол-ва данных для приёмного буфера сокета".

То есть - да, данные готовы, можно читать.

Как я понял, poll и epoll - это лишь "наворот", работающий аналогично select, но позволяющий при вызове получить дополнительную информацию. Так что логика в смысле готовности сокета отличаться не должна.

Comment: Спасибо за пометку моего ответа как "хорошего ответа", но когда напишете код - напишите в комментариях, что всё так и работает, как написано в книжке? А то самому уже интересно:-)

Comment: Да, всё работает верно, как только отсылаю данные с сервера, сразу poll возвращает 1, как только их считываю, и данных в буфере сокета нет, то возвращает 0

Answer (score 3):

select сообщает о том, что ядро готово читать/писать данные из/в сокет. То есть, в буфере есть место - можно ещё писать, но по факту данные могли ещё не уйти. С чтением все проще - если сокет можно читать, значит там есть хотя бы один байт данных (ну или сокет закрылся). Если говорить точно, то то, что сокет доступен для чтения значит ровно то, что последующая операция чтения с него не будет заблокирована. Именно это написано в манах https://www.opennet.ru/cgi-bin/opennet/man.cgi?topic=select&category=2

> Те, что перечислены в readfds, будут отслеживаться для того, чтобы обнаружить появление символов, доступных для чтения (говоря более точно, чтобы узнать, не будет ли блокировано чтение; описатель файла также будет указывать на конец файла)

Вы пишете:

> Я правильно понимаю, что poll/select позволяют отследить, что на сокет именно пришли некие данные, или только то, что он может отправлять/принимать данные физически, так сказать?

Именно то, что пришли данные, а то, что он может принимать данные - это просто наличие корректно установленного соединения (если с той стороны никто не отправляет данные, то физически сокет может принимать данные, но вот что принимать?)

Также в вопросе прослеживается некое желание читать одновременно с двух потоков с одного сокета. Так можно сделать, но но не стоит. Лучше читать одному сокету, а потом уже распихать по нужным потребителям.